# class method to get array of attributes from managed object subclass?

Tags: ios, core-data

I know that I can get an array of attributes from an instance of a managed object, like so:

```
[[[myManagedObject entity] attributesByName] allKeys]
```

But what if I don't want to instantiate myManagedObject, and just want to ask its class for an array of its attributes? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the entity description from the *managed object context*

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = 
                         [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"YourEntityName" 
                                     inManagedObjectContext:yourContext];
```

or from the *managed object model*

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [yourModel entitiesByName][@"YourEntityName"];
```

without instantiating an instance of that entity,
and then retrieve the attributes, for example

```
NSArray *attributes = [[entityDesc attributesByName] allKeys];
```

Comment: Just wondering… why does an entity description object need to be created in a managed object context, even though it does not become part of a persistent store when the context is saved? Thanks

Comment: @mkc842: Good question! It is because the context knows about the Core Data *model*. Alternatively, you could get the entity descriptions from the NSManagedObjectModel directly.